# Datatables serverside info + static colum with 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm struggeling to make a static column with 2 buttons that trigger 2 links with dynamic data. I managed to make 1 button work but i can't make the other. I tried adding an id to each one and call different functions for each one but it seems it's only working with `$(\'#example tbody \')` and not `($(\'#customID \')`.

Here is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $(\'#example\').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "app/server_processing.php",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button>Edit</button> <button>Delete</button>"
        } ]
    } );
     $(\'#example tbody \').on( \'click\', \'button\', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents(\'tr\') ).data();
        window.location.href = "index.php?categ=edit&id="+ data[0];
    } );
} );
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $(\'#example\').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "app/server_processing.php",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button id="edit">Edit</button> <button id="delete">Delete</button>"
        } ]
    } );
     $(\'#example tbody \').on( \'click\', \'#edit\', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents(\'tr\') ).data();
        window.location.href = "index.php?categ=edit&id="+ data[0];
    } );
 $(\'#example tbody \').on( \'click\', \'#delete\', function () {
        var data = table.row( $(this).parents(\'tr\') ).data();
        window.location.href = "index.php?categ=delete&id="+ data[0];
    } );
} );
        </script>
```